# Lumen request validation not working

Tags: laravel, lumen, php-7.1

In my `.env` file I have the following setting for my production server:

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
```

In laravel\lumen docs it's said that if we are running the project on production server we should set `APP_DEBUG` to `false` and change `APP_ENV` from `local` to `production`, for example. When I do so lumen's request validation stops working. But when I set `APP_DEBUG` to `true` request validation is working as expected. Am I missing something?

P.S. Production server environment PHP version is 7.1.12

**UPDATE**

Also I have the following code in `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` render method, which I think also affects the behavior:

```
if (env('APP_DEBUG')) {
  return parent::render($request, $e);
}

$message = 'Внутренняя ошибка на сервере';
$response_code = 500;

if ($e instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException) {
  $message = 'Запрос не разрешен (неправильный метод запроса)';
  $response_code = 405;
}
elseif ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
  $message = 'Указан неверный адрес конечной точки API';
  $response_code = 404;
}
elseif ($e instanceof AuthorizationException) {
  $message = 'Отказ в доступе (нет прав на доступ)';
  $response_code = 403;
}
elseif ($e instanceof FatalThrowableError || $e instanceof \ErrorException) 
{
  $message = 'Неверный запрос URL-адреса (проверьте поля запроса)';
  $response_code = 400;
}
elseif ($e instanceof QueryException) {
  $message = 'Нарушение целостности базы данных';
  $response_code = 406;
}

return response()->json([
  'success' => false,
  'errors' => [
    [
      'id' => 'default',
      'message' => $message
    ]
  ]
], $response_code);
```

If I set `APP_ENV=production` and `APP_DEBUG=false`, Exception's render method returns its json responses instead of validation responses.

Comment: you need response validation message ? json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that you don't handle here `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException`.

Depending on your needs you might want to change:

```
if (env('APP_DEBUG')) {
  return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

into

```
if (env('APP_DEBUG') || $e instanceof \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException) {
  return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

or add additional `elseif` block that will do what you want when `$e` is instanceof `\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException`

Comment: I thought it is already handled because it is in $dontReport array, but later I realized these two are not related at all, thanks a lot